# Equivalent for XML value function in SQL Server for PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In SQL Server, the code looks like this:

```
CAST(XML AS XML).value('(xpath here','nvarchar(50)')
```

What is the equivalent in PostgresSQL?

Comment: Does the `xpath` function described at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html help you? e.g. SELECT xpath('/my:a/text()', '<my:a xmlns:my="http://example.com">test</my:a>',
             ARRAY[ARRAY['my', 'http://example.com']]);

Answer (score 0):

you can CAST in postgres a xml text with ::xml

second you can use xpath to get the data

```
CREATE TABLE x_ml (xm_l text)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT  INTO x_ml VALUES ( '<category>

<book>

<price>20 USD</price>

</book>

</category>')
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
SELECT xpath('/category/book/price/text()', xm_l::xml) from x_ml
```

| xpath |
| --- |
| {"20 USD"} |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

```
SELECT  (xpath('/category/book/price/text()', xm_l::xml))[1] from x_ml
```

| xpath |
| --- |
| 20 USD |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nbuhckme)

Comment: Thank you, sounds good.  How do you get rid of those brackets around the returned data, though?

Comment: That is text so you can replace it

Comment: xpath() returns an array, just pick the result you want, like the first one: SELECT (xpath('/category/book/price/text()', xm_l::xml))[1] from x_ml